R BigQuery: Exporting data to Google Cloud Storage in parquet format
I'm trying to export queried data from a BigQuery database table.
Since the resulting table can be large (2.5GB or more), I followed the suggestion "Larger datasets" from the bq_table_download() help, and I used bq_table_save() to save the data in multiple files in Google Cloud Storage.
When I tried to apply bq_table_save(), I discovered an undocumented option to export the files:
destination_format = "PARQUET"
in place of "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON" or "CSV".
If I use this parameter, bq_table_save() saves correctly the data in multiple "parquet" files.
Can I use this option without problems? It seems to me that it works very well: it is very performant, and the use of parquet files saves me a lot of work to check data types.
The following code summarizes at most the code I used to export data succesfully to a Google Cloud Storage bucket:
project_id  <- "<project identifier>"
sql_dwn <- "SELECT * FROM <table from which to extract data>"
tb <- bq_project_query(project_id, sql_dwn)
bq_table_save(tb, destination_uris = "destination_bucket/folder/filename_*.parquet", destination_format="PARQUET") 

Thank you in advance for your suggestions/hints.
Enrico

When you say the option is undocumented, can you please provide a link to the documentation that you are reading?

@Kolban yes, of course.
Here the help of bq_table_save(): https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/reference/api-table.html
Here the help of bq_perform_extract(), used by of bq_table_save() to save the data:  https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/reference/api-perform.html?q=bq_perform_extract#null
Thank you

I'd be tempted to suggest that you go to the open source hom of the library in question which appears to be here ... https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/issues   Go to the issues section and create an issue asking for clarification directly from the owners.  They will be able to advise on the supportedness of the story ... it may be that there is a documentation omission and they will a appreciative of hearing from you.

Thank you Kolban. I'll try it for sure..
